# Exposing an API to a Tapestry web application

Tags: java, api, mobile, tapestry

I am working on a Tapestry 5 based web application that should expose an API to iPhone and Android devices. Currently the API is implemented using the built in MVC capabilities of tapestry. E.g all the services are handler methods that return JSON strings in Tapestry page classes dedicated to mobile access. Authentication is done with Spring Security and every user is bound to a session. I'm rather new to this stuff, so correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't seem like a very clean solution.

What are possible drawbacks to this solutions?
What are significiant advantages when using a REST-API instead?
What would be best practice in such a case?

Answer (score 5):

Try [Tapestry-RestEasy](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-resteasy+guide)

Answer (score 1):

For SeeSaw.com we have similar requirements to expose feeds from our T5 web application and have tried a number of different approaches.

For read only data we expose write a T5 page/component that renders XML (or JSON) as a feed. For read/write data we implement tapestry OnXXX events via JSON. By splitting it out this way you get a more efficient site (as the read only stuff can be cached).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help ...

[Template Skinning](http://blog.tapestry5.de/index.php/2011/06/24/template-skinning/)

To quote from the article

> In this article I want to share with you a new awesome Tapestry feature introduced in 5.3. This feature allows you to provide different skins for a single page by creating several templates. These different templates are used by Tapestry to render the same page in a special way for different clients. For example, when developing a web application for both standard and mobile clients you might need to render the same page different depending on the current client. So, you need to create two different templates for each page and choose one of them depending on the user agent sent by the client.

This might be the "clean solution" you are looking for? Cheers!

Murray...